# Sketch app input field value not increase/decrease with arrows key

Tags: keyboard, applications, permission, shortcut, restart

I am running Catalina on my MacBook Pro mid 2014 retina.
From few days I am having strange issue with my Sketch app. I can’t increase/decrease input values from arrows key. When I select any input field and press arrow up it suppose to be increase the value and on press arrow it suppose to be decrease the value. Even input spinner not working on click. It only works when I type numbers and hit enter.

I checked my other apps Photoshop, Illustrator, Invision Studio all apps are working fine.
The issue is only happening with Sketch app.
I tried to install fresh copy (updated version).
I tried to uninstall Sketch app with app cleaner.
I restore defaults keyboard shortcuts.
I restore defaults Accessibility settings but no success.
For the reference I attached image what i want to get back.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I updated my system from Catalina to Big Sur and everything working fine.